# Migrate hbase snapshot from 0.94 to 0.98

Tags: hbase

I am trying to migrate a hbase snapshot from hbase version 0.94 to 0.98.

Steps:

1. Create snapshot on old hbase 0.94

   snapshot 'test_event_raw_data', 'test_event_raw_data'
2. export to hbase 0.98

   hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.ExportSnapshot -snapshot test_event_raw_data -copy-to hdfs://:8020/apps/hbase/data -mappers 16

   Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4 
   at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1118) 
   at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229) 
   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source) 
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)

Can anyone help me understand this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to run ExportSnapshot from the .98 cluster, and use -copy-from hftp://source-cluster
The different versions aren't hdfs-compatible, but they're compatible at the hftp / webhdfs layers